# Lazy look and say sequence

Tags: homework, clojure, lazy

I have been solving a set of online Clojure problems.  One of them involves the [look and say sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Look-and-say_sequence).

```
(defn look-and-say [s]
   (let [las (loop [item (first s) coll s counts [] count 0]
      (cond
         (nil? (seq coll)) (conj counts count item)
         (= item (first coll)) (recur item (rest coll) counts (inc count))
         :else  (recur (first coll)  coll (conj counts count item) 0)))]
      (lazy-seq (cons las (look-and-say las)))))
```

I would like know what I did right and what I could do better. Any feedback is welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

one of the great things about Clojure is the ability to seperate code into concerns and then compose them. This really helps spot reusable parts and lets you build code in smaller independently testable parts.

the parts I see are:

- given a sequence of number produce the next one

  - `partition-all` the seq into groups of consecutive numbers
  - for each group of consecutive numbers say how many there are `(map say list-o-groups)`
  - `flatten` the result into one list. but really you should use `mapcat` in the previous step and skip this step.
- apply the the result to the same function (the `iterate` function)
- `take` as many of these as you need

Comment: Bluggghhhhh `map` followed by `flatten` is vile, don't recommend it. Just use `mapcat`.

Comment: yes, mapcat is better. It makes for a less clear explanation of "separating concerns". I will edit to note this :)